# Having problems with detecting leap year

Tags: c++, epoch, leap-year

avHi again,
thank you all for the help in my previous problem.

However now i have encountered another problem

```
int main ()
    {
        int inputSeconds,seconds, minutes, hours , days ,years ;
        int remainingSeconds ;
        int current_year = 1970;
        int current_month = 1;
        int current_day = 1;
        const int standard_year = 365;
        const int leap_year = 366;
        bool leapYear;
        int leapcounter  ; //Since 1972 is the next closest leap year, counter is set to 2


        cout << "Welcome to Epoch time/ Data converter" << endl;
        cout << "Enter Number of Seconds Since Midnight Jan 1, 1970: ";
        cin >> inputSeconds ;


        //Convert seconds into days to determine the number of years that has already passed


        days = inputSeconds/(60*60*24) ;
        remainingSeconds = inputSeconds % (60*60*24) ;


        cout << days << endl; 
        //Determine current year 

            while (!(days < 365))
            {
            if (leapcounter == 3 )
                {
                    current_year++;
                    days -= leap_year;
                    leapYear = true;
                    leapcounter = 0;

                }
            else
                {


                    current_year++;
                    days -= standard_year;
                    leapcounter++;  
                    leapYear = false;

                }
            } 


            //Check if current year is leap year or not

            if ((current_year % 4 == 0) && (current_year % 100 == 0) || (current_year % 400 == 0))
                leapYear = true;
            else
                leapYear = false;



        cout << current_year << " days remaining :" << days << " Leap year? " << leapYear << " Remaining seconds :" << remainingSeconds;

        return 0;
```

}

it doesnt seem to be detecting a leap year on the output. 
I have tried 1972, 2004,2008,and 2012.

I cant seem to figure out the problem with it and is hoping you could help shed light on my problem
thank you in advance.

Comment: In your program you state that the user has to input the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch. How are you entering your times? As 1972, 2004, etc? Or, as UNIX timestamps?

Comment: in unix time ,1325376000 , etc etc

Answer (score 1):

The logic for deciding a leap year from `current_year` is a bit more complex than what you have.

It needs to be:

```
if ((current_year % 4 == 0) )
{
  if ( (current_year % 100 == 0) )
  {
     if ( (current_year % 400 == 0) )
     {
        leapYear = true;
     }
     else
     {
        leapYear = false;
     }
  }
  else
  {
     leapYear = true;
  }
}
else
{
  leapYear = false;
}
```

On further thinking, that logic can be simplified to:

```
leapYear = ( (current_year % 400) == 0 ||
             ( (current_year % 4) == 0 && (current_year % 100) != 0)) ;
```

Also, you need to initialize `leapcounter` to `2` since day `1` corresponds to the first day of `1970` -- 2 years since the previous leap year.

Comment: yup! that did the trick. thank you. do you mind explaining why if has to branch out that way?

Comment: A bit prolixic code you have there, see my answer for something more  succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
bool IsALeapYear(int year) {
    return (!(year % 4) && (year % 100)) || !(year % 400);
}
```